# New Monetisation system on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I have a channel on YouTube and unlike those "soccer skills and tricks" videos, i upload only videos of top goals from latest matches (30 to 40 seconds long).

Now, my channel is growing at a good rate (without any paid views) but according to new Monetisation system, you should have atleast 10,000 all-time views to be eligible for Monetisation and after reaching 10,000 views, channel will be checked for (voilating or not) community guidelines.

What are the chances that my channel will pass this test and i can monetize.

(None of my videos have copyright strike and none of them have logo like "BeinSports", "FS1" etc. )

Answer (score 0):

YouTube came up with the [10k views policy](http://www.india.com/business/new-youtube-monetization-policy-video-creators-will-need-10000-lifetime-views-to-mint-money-2003140/) to prevent spammers and channels that make money with offensive content.

So as long as your videos are legit without any copyright strikes, there shouldn't be any problem. In any case, your real worry should begin *after* your channel is monetized. Countless channels, big and small, have criticized YouTube's incessant and often invalid strikes just because some big company claimed so. Watch this by [Chriss Stuckmann](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I55seO4d1Kw) to know what I mean. I highly recommend it for YouTube creators, especially those new in the game.

And finally learn more about [Youtube Fair Use](https://www.youtube.com/yt/copyright/fair-use.html).

Good luck!